# Recorded screen video is not good size, smaller than the frame

Tags: android, video

I am trying to record a video in my Android Studio but the video that display of this record is not that i want - it shows a container with video and empty space covered with black.

Here it is:

[image]

I recorded in Android Studio 3.0.1 using Samsung S6 Edge+.

I left everything by default in the configuration screen of the recording video and just start recording.

How to get rid of the unesserary empty black space?

Answer (score 3):

- Go to Phone settings
- Open Display settings
- Change `Screen resolution` while you have video in desired canvas

[image: This how changing of Screen resolution looks like on my S7 Edge]